Android PackageManager Permissions question
Hi I am trying to write an app to get a list of installed user apps.  I've read that in 2023 Android blocked access to this feature.  I cannot figure out if there is still a way to get a list of installed user apps.  I am looking to get list of user apps that I have written and installed.  I am not looking to get general list of all apps.  I know the expected list of apps by name.  Is this still possible?  If so how is it done?
Thanks.
In my research it appears that Android blocked this feature in 2023.  All examples I have found are dated pre 2023.  I am unable to find a newer example.

I believe that's still the case, however you should be able to check for a specific package name?

"In my research it appears that Android blocked this feature in 2023" -- did you follow the instructions in the documentation? If yes, and it still is not working, please post a [mcve] and explain in detail the results that you are getting.
